# Groovy compiling despite error in function arguments

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovy-eclipse

Is this legal in Groovy?

```
class RequestContext {
    def static requestContext

    def static setRequestContext(rc) {
        requestContext = rc
    }
}
```

Given the above I expect the following to fail at compile time using the groovy-eclipse-compiler:

`RequestContext.setRequestContext()`

Yet this passes and I'm trying to get this to fail at `mvn compile` time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't fail at compile time, because you might add that method dynamically at runtime via the metaclass, ie:

```
class Test {
}

Test.metaClass.static.woo = { -> println "yay" }

Test.woo() // prints 'yay'
```

To fail at compile time, you'd need to annotate the calling class with `@CompileStatic` or `@TypeChecked`